# Terraform Azure Databricks Unity Catalogue - Failed to check metastore quota limit for region

Tags: azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, databricks-unity-catalog, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to create a metastore via the Terraform Azure databricks_metastore resource but I keep getting the error:

```
Error: cannot create metastore: Failed to check metastore quota limit for region westeurope.
```

This is the exact code I am using to create the resource:

```
# Create the databricks metastore and assign it to the databricks workspace
resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
  name          = "databricksmetastore"
  storage_root  = "abfss://databrickscontainerrr@databricksstorageee.dfs.core.windows.net/"
  region        = "westeurope"
  owner         = ""
}
```

I have tried using both my Databricks account and a service principal application id, which are both in fact Account Admins, for the owner argument in the code block above to no avail.

[image]

[image]

Needless to say, there is no metastore in the region I am trying to create it in and if I use the GUI with my account I am able to successfully create and assign the metastore to the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to trouble shoot the Issue Azure Databricks Unity Catalogue - Failed to check metastore quota limit for region and I was able to provision requirement successfully.

It seems you're encountering an issue creating a Databricks metastore in the West Europe region using Terraform. The error message suggests a problem with checking the metastore quota limit, which could be due to a few different reasons.

1. **Quota Limits:** Your Azure subscription might have reached its quota limits for the resource you are trying to create.
2. **Region Availability:** There might be temporary unavailability or restrictions in the `westeurope` region.

This Issue can be overcome by making the changes in the type of data bricks account provisioned to **Premium** and by **changing the region** to any other available region which is readily available in the list of regions supported by Azure Databricks metastore. Here the region mentioned by you was allocated globally not a dedicated one associated with your Account subscription alone.

Here for our convenience, I tried using **`westus`** from the [list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/resources/supported-regions) of available region for the requirement you asked for.

**My terraform configuration:**

```kotlin
terraform {
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source = "databricks/databricks"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "enter your subscription id"
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  name = "Vinay"
}

data "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "this" {
  name                = "Vinay-databricks"
  resource_group_name = "Vinay"
}

provider "databricks" {
  host = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.workspace_url
}

resource "azurerm_databricks_access_connector" "unity" {
  name                = "vinaydatabricksmi"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "unity_catalog" {
  name                     = "thejadatabricksdemo"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"
  is_hns_enabled           = true
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "unity_catalog" {
  name                  = "vinay-container"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.unity.identity[0].principal_id
}

resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
  name     = "primary"
  storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    azurerm_storage_container.unity_catalog.name,
  azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name)
  force_destroy = true
  region        = "westus"
}
```

**Output:**

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am able to replicate your code on my end and even switched to westus but when I get to the creation of the metastore via terraform I am now hit with "Error: cannot create metastore: User is not an account admin for Account." As before, I am able to create the metastore for westus using the databricks GUI and I am in fact the global admin of the azure directory. Do you, by any chance, have a premium databricks account? I am starting to think the issue might be there.

Comment: Yes, You need a premium account for the configuration you're looking for.

refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/automate#before-you-begin